# Accessing object from map causes instantiation of new object C++

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

I have a big class (call it Collection) and a small class (Item).

Upon initialization of a Collection object it creates a vector of maps to the small objects. The overall structure looks like:

```
vector<map<int,Item>> storage;
```

Specifically it looks like:

```
vector<map<int,Node>> layers;
```

So when I call a method of Collection to access Item, i.e.

```
layers[vector_index][map_index].some_method();
```

it forces Item to be reinitialized. Here's the specific code:

```
void NN::set_hidden_weights(int hidden_layer_num,int node_index,map<int,double> new_weights){
    layers[hidden_layer_num][node_index].set_weights(new_weights); //updates weights
}
```

What I mean is that I get the following error from my compiler:

```
 g++ -o tests.exe tests.cpp ../src/neural_network.cpp -std=c++11
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_map.h:63:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/map:61,
                 from ../src/neural_network.cpp:8:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/tuple: In instantiation of ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::tuple<_Args1 ...>&, std::tuple<_Args2 ...>&, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes1 ...>, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes2 ...>) [with _Args1 = {const int&}; long unsigned int ..._Indexes1 = {0ul}; _Args2 = {}; long unsigned int ..._Indexes2 = {}; _T1 = const int; _T2 = Node]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/tuple:1079:63:   required from ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::piecewise_construct_t, std::tuple<_Args1 ...>, std::tuple<_Args2 ...>) [with _Args1 = {const int&}; _Args2 = {}; _T1 = const int; _T2 = Node]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h:140:49:   required from ‘std::_Rb_tree_node<_Val>::_Rb_tree_node(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple<const int&>, std::tuple<>}; _Val = std::pair<const int, Node>]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/ext/new_allocator.h:120:4:   required from ‘void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const int, Node> >; _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple<const int&>, std::tuple<>}; _Tp = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const int, Node> >]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/alloc_traits.h:254:4:   required from ‘static typename std::enable_if<std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::__construct_helper<_Tp, _Args>::value, void>::type std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::_S_construct(_Alloc&, _Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const int, Node> >; _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple<const int&>, std::tuple<>}; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const int, Node> > >; typename std::enable_if<std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::__construct_helper<_Tp, _Args>::value, void>::type = void]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/alloc_traits.h:393:57:   required from ‘static decltype (_S_construct(__a, __p, (forward<_Args>)(std::allocator_traits::construct::__args)...)) std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::construct(_Alloc&, _Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const int, Node> >; _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple<const int&>, std::tuple<>}; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const int, Node> > >; decltype (_S_construct(__a, __p, (forward<_Args>)(std::allocator_traits::construct::__args)...)) = <type error>]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h:408:36:   required from ‘std::_Rb_tree_node<_Val>* std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_create_node(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple<const int&>, std::tuple<>}; _Key = int; _Val = std::pair<const int, Node>; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const int, Node> >; _Compare = std::less<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, Node> >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Link_type = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const int, Node> >*]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h:1669:64:   required from ‘std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_emplace_hint_unique(std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple<const int&>, std::tuple<>}; _Key = int; _Val = std::pair<const int, Node>; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const int, Node> >; _Compare = std::less<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, Node> >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, Node> >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const int, Node> >]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_map.h:465:8:   required from ‘std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](const key_type&) [with _Key = int; _Tp = Node; _Compare = std::less<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, Node> >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = Node; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = int]’
../src/neural_network.cpp:135:27:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/tuple:1090:70: error: no matching function for call to ‘Node::Node()’
         second(std::forward<_Args2>(std::get<_Indexes2>(__tuple2))...)
                                                                      ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/tuple:1090:70: note: candidates are:
../src/neural_network.cpp:12:1: note: Node::Node(int, std::vector<int>)
 Node::Node(int node_index, vector<int> input_indices){
 ^
../src/neural_network.cpp:12:1: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
In file included from ../src/neural_network.cpp:9:0:
../src/neural_network.hpp:12:7: note: Node::Node(const Node&)
 class Node{
       ^
../src/neural_network.hpp:12:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
../src/neural_network.hpp:12:7: note: Node::Node(Node&&)
../src/neural_network.hpp:12:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

I don't have a default constructor for my Item class nor a copy constructor, and at any rate what I really want to do is manipulate the Item itself, not a copy of it. Does anyone have any recommendations on how to proceed? I'm really confused why I'm getting these initialization errors when the object Item is already created.

Answer (score 2):

Invocation of indexing operator on map `layers[hidden_layer_num][node_index]` causes a new map to be constructed (if it wasn't there yet) with `node_index` as key and default constructed value. You should use `map::find()` to access already present items.

Comment: @Gim Use of operator []  on std::map _requires_ a default constructor. Use find() instead.

Comment: If it is already there then no changed will be made to map, however value type is still required to have a default constructor.